# Packaged build environment as build_requires of profiles, system compiler is used instead

Tags: conan

I will try to describe my setup first:

- conan 1.29.2
- Official `cmake/3.18.2` package
- Custom `gcc` package with **`package_info` including its bin directory in `PATH` and setting the `CC` and `CXX` env variables**:

  ```py
  def package(self):
      autotools = AutoToolsBuildEnvironment(self)
      autotools.make(target='install-strip')

  def package_info(self):
      bin_folder = os.path.join(self.package_folder, 'bin')

      self.env_info.path.append(bin_folder)
      self.env_info.CXX = os.path.join(bin_folder, 'g++')
      self.env_info.CC = os.path.join(bin_folder, 'gcc')
  ```
- `linux-x86_64` conan profile representing Linux 64 bit environment as follows:

  ```
  [settings]
  os=Linux
  os_build=Linux
  arch=x86_64
  arch_build=x86_64
  ```
- `linux-x86_64-Debug` conan profile representing Linux 64 bit Release environment as follows:

  ```
  include(linux-x86_64)

  [settings]
  build_type=Debug
  ```
- `gcc-10.1.0` conan profile to build packages using my `gcc` package:

  ```
  [settings]
  compiler=gcc
  compiler.version=10.1
  compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11

  [build_requires]
  gcc/10.1.0
  ```
- `cmake-3.18.2` conan profile to build packages using official `cmake` package:

  ```
  [build_requires]
  cmake/3.18.2
  ```
- `default` conan profile with gcc 7

If I try to build a package as follows:

```sh
$ conan create . foo/version --build=missing -pr linux-x86_64-Debug -pr cmake-3.18.2 -pr gcc-10.1.0
```

the resulting config is:

```
Configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Debug
compiler=gcc
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=10.1
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
[options]
[build_requires]
*: gcc/10.1.0, cmake/3.18.2
[env]
```

*which looks right to me...*

and then conan starts building `cmake` package for the gcc 10.1 x86_64 config:

```
cmake/3.18.2: WARN: Build folder is dirty, removing it: /home/manuel/.conan/data/cmake/3.18.2/_/_/build/46c0026dddc0e0537a797652343e8e1e9d0e39e7
cmake/3.18.2: Copying sources to build folder
cmake/3.18.2: Building your package in /home/manuel/.conan/data/cmake/3.18.2/_/_/build/46c0026dddc0e0537a797652343e8e1e9d0e39e7
cmake/3.18.2: Generator cmake created conanbuildinfo.cmake
cmake/3.18.2: Calling build()
```

But then build fails because the `cmake` package cmake config **is using the system compiler**:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Conan: called by CMake conan helper
-- Conan: called inside local cache
-- Conan: Adjusting output directories
-- Conan: Using cmake global configuration
-- Conan: Adjusting default RPATHs Conan policies
-- Conan: Adjusting language standard
-- Conan: Compiler GCC>=5, checking major version 10.1
-- Conan: Checking correct version: 7.4
CMake Error at ../conanbuildinfo.cmake:510 (message):
  Detected a mismatch for the compiler version between your conan profile
  settings and CMake:

  Compiler version specified in your conan profile: 10.1

  Compiler version detected in CMake: 7.4

  Please check your conan profile settings (conan profile show
  [default|your_profile_name])

  P.S.  You may set CONAN_DISABLE_CHECK_COMPILER CMake variable in order to
  disable this check.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ../conanbuildinfo.cmake:592 (conan_error_compiler_version)
  ../conanbuildinfo.cmake:695 (check_compiler_version)
  ../conanbuildinfo.cmake:249 (conan_check_compiler)
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (conan_basic_setup)
```

This looks very similar to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/1842, but that issue is from 3 years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conan learned some versions ago about *host* and *build* contexts and is able to manage different configurations for those contexts. This is preferred over the old `os_build` and `arch_build` settings and packages in ConanCenter are moving towards this new feature.

In your scenario, you are trying to build a `library` using packages `gcc` and `cmake` as build-requires. You are building `library` for the *host* machine and using package `gcc` and `cmake` that provide tools that should run in the *build* machine. Even if you are not cross-compiling, we can agree that native building is just a specific use-case where *host* and *build* are the same machine and, hence, they use the same Conan configuration.

Back to your example. You need your profiles for the *host* platform, the one you want to generate your `library` for. These are all the profiles you have listed in your question. But you also need a profile for the *build* context, the profile that Conan will use to build (or retrieve) the `gcc` and `cmake` packages. For example, you might want to use a profile `linux-x86_64-Debug` to compile your `library` in debug mode, while using `gcc` and `cmake` in Release.

Typically, the profile for your *build* context can be the default profile detected by Conan.

Try this command instead of yours (note the `--profile:build=default`):

```
conan create <library/conanfile.py> foo/version --build=missing --profile:host linux-x86_64-Debug --profile:host cmake-3.18.2 --profile:host gcc-10.1.0 --profile:build=default
```

Now Conan will use the new feature and assign the package to the corresponding contexts:

- `library` and all its dependencies will be assigned to the *host* context and will use information from all the `--profile:host` profiles: your Debug build and Conan will add `cmake` and `gcc` as build-requires.
- `gcc` and `cmake`, as they are build-requires in this command, will be assigned to the *build* context and will use the information from the `--profile:build`. If Conan needs to build these packages it will use the settings from that profile, not the settings for the *host* profiles.

**With this setup you can build all packages in a cross-building scenario in a single run**: packages in the *host* context will use your build-requires `gcc` to build, while packages in the *build* context will use the tools defined in the `--profile:build`.

Yes, in this scenario, packages in the *build* context will use the compiler from your system.... unless you declare `[build_requires]` inside the `--profile:build`.

Comment: so the issue is that I was mixing my host settings with my build settings. Is there a way to tell conan to use an specific profile as build profile by default?

Comment: Not in Conan v1.x (changing it would be breaking behavior). Conan v2 might use a `--profile:build=default` by default (still to be defined)

Comment: there were ages when people knew that "host" is just a wildcard for any sort of current machine. and at the same ages people called the machine that the codes shall run upon the "target". these once were ages were there was no space left for any sort of confusion.